# crmod crm soap request returning more than 100 records

Tags: xml, oracle, soap, crm

I'm trying to generate a crmod request which will return more than 100 rows and the pagesize is set to max of 100 on the server. I'm having trouble implementing the solution. My request query for account is:

```
<quer:ListOfAccount StartRowNum="PageSize+1" pagesize="100" lastpage="false">
```

Is there something further I need to do as when I open the response file? It still contains 100 records.